# Display webcam uploaded image and datetime

Tags: javascript, html

I have a webcam that ftp uploads an image every 3 minutes.
I need a script to refresh this image and display the last image's creation date & time.

I 've tried the following code, but does not display the datetime

```
<HTML>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function refreshIt(){
      url='image_1.jpg';
      try{
        var Oxml= new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        Oxml.open("HEAD", url, false);
        Oxml.send(null);
        if(Oxml.status== 200){
           var lastMod = new Date(Oxml.getResponseHeader('Last-Modified')).toLocaleString();
           document.getElementById('getImageDate').innerHTML=lastMod;
           document.images['webcam'].src =url + '?' +  Math.random();
        }
      }
      catch(e){}
      setTimeout('refreshIt()',180000); // refresh every 3 minutes
    </script> 
  </head>

  <body onload="setTimeout('refreshIt()',180000)">
    <div align="center">
       <img id="webcam" src="image_1.jpg" alt="webcam" />
       <p><span id="getImageDate">Photo Timestamp</span></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<HTML>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">  

function ShowCurrentTime() {
var dt = new Date();
document.getElementById("lblMessage").innerHTML = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
window.setTimeout("ShowCurrentTime()", 1000); // Here 1000(milliseconds) means one 1 Sec  
}

        function AutoReloader(picName, picSource) { // HTML name, IMG src
            if (document.images && document.images[picName]) { // test for script support
                var day = new Date(); // current date and time
                var n = day.getYear() + day.getMonth() + day.getDate() + day.getTime();
                var tag = document.images[picName]; // shortcut the original image object
                var newPic = new Image(tag.width, tag.height); // create image instance
                var ary = picSource.split("?pic", 1); // get image address
                newPic.src = ary[0] + "?pic" + n; // load new image with query
                tag.src = newPic.src; // display new image
                var txt = "Web camera image for "
   + day.getMonth() + "/" + day.getDate() + "/" + day.getYear() + " at "
   + day.getHours() + ":" + ((day.getMinutes() < 10) ? "0" : "") + day.getMinutes()
   + ":" + ((day.getSeconds() < 10) ? "0" : "") + day.getSeconds() + ".";
                tag.alt = txt; tag.parentNode.title = txt; // update image and div text
             document.getElementById("lblMessage").innerHTML = txt;
            }
        }
        function updatePic(picName, picSource, timer) { // HTML name, IMG src, time in seconds
            setInterval("AutoReloader('" + picName + "','" + picSource + "')", timer * 1000);
        }   
</script> 
  </head>

  <body onload="ShowCurrentTime()">
    <div align="center">
      <p align="center" title="Web camera image."><img alt="Web camera image." src="ImageSource" name="UniqueName" width="ImageWidth" height="ImageHeight" onload="updatePic(this.name,this.src,RefreshTime);" /> <label id="lblMessage" ForeColor="Red"></label></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: I 've tried your code but still datetime does not show.
I used :
<p align="center" title="Web camera image."><img alt="Web camera image." src="image_1.jpg" name="Webcam" onload="updatePic(this.name,this.src,180);" /></p>

Comment: Correction: I 've tried your code and it works if I mouse over the image. But I need to display that datetime under my image.

Comment: Also when I first open (or refresh) that page the datetime is not shown.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I am not very experienced. Can you show me how to do that ?

Comment: It works. The only problem I have to solve now is how to show the datetime when the image in first loaded. It now shows only after the first auto refresh. And year in label is displayed like this: Web camera image for 5/4/114 at 13:45:25

Comment: After more testing, this script does not work how I want. It displays the date & time the refresh occurs and not the datetime the image was uploaded.

Comment: As I said earlier, I need to display the datetime of the last image upload by my webcam and not the current (refresh) datetime. Your code displays the current datetime.